# html - How to align tables in top?

Tags: html

I have created more than one table in row alignment,but all the tables are not adjacent,how to set the alignment for all the tables?

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No super powers here, where's the markup?

Comment: what is markup,i couldn't get you?

Comment: @avrmraja post your code

Comment: Seriously? Just Google what's markup, and don't go ahead with web before knowing what's markup

Comment: @avrmraja he means post your html file (xml)

Comment: I posted the Html file,but it shows the content,how can i post html code here

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using CSS

```
td {
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try to add this to your tables

```
<table style="display: inline-block;">

<table style="float: left;">
```